# Android: open tripadvisor app

Tags: android

is there a way to open the tripadvisor app from another app on a specified restaurant just like we do for Facebook Pages or the play store?

Somenthig like this:

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("/*tripadvisor package*/", 0);
        return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("trip://resturant/313689422066566"));
```

I tried searching on the internet but found nothing useful. Does anyone knows?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way ... If you try to write:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link_tripadvisor));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
```

it gives you the chance to choose if open it using the browser or the application

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
Intent i;
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
try {
 i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("app package name");
if (i == null)
    throw new PackageManager.NameNotFoundException();
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startActivity(i);
   } 
catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
}
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't know the tripadvisor package name, and even if i know it i don't know how to create a URL to show the desired restaurant

Comment: What info do you have regarding restaurants ?

Comment: i've the link to the tripadvisor page

Comment: I don't think this is possible... because there is no documentation on his and I also check for Tripadvisor API, you need a license to use it. You may want to load a simple webview ?

Comment: yeah...i suspect this...i've also checked for the api some time ago....yeah i will go for the webview thanks :)